# Bootstrap Navbar Background-Image

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Já tentei de tudo aqui no código e não tem jeito, não consigo fazer a `navbar` do bootstrap ter a imagem. O mais bizarro é que no Safari ela aparece, no Chrome não.

Segue o código:

```
.navbar {
        background: url("bootstrap/images/nav-bar.png") repeat-x !important;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Já tentei inclusive de outra maneira, assim:

```
.admin-bar .navbar-fixed-top {
        background: url("bootstrap/images/nav-bar.png") repeat-x;
        background-size: cover;
        border-style: none;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
```

De jeito nenhum vai. Se possível alguém dar uma ajuda, tá complicado demais descobrir. Como disse, o estranho é que no Safari ela aparece, no Chrome fica sem nada, só os links como se não tivesse nada atrás, transparente.

Comment: Possivelmente é erro no caminho até a imagem. Dá uma verificada se o CSS está realmente encontrando a imagem.

Comment: Verifique as ferramentas de desenvolvimento se o CSS chega a ser aplicado e esta sendo sobre-posto por outra regra, e se a imagem esta realmente sendo buscada (status 200).

Comment: Pessoal, muito obrigado! O link estava correto, mas como vocês pediram para eu ver novamente, fui prestar atenção na imagem que ele tava chamando, e o problema por incrível que pareça era o PNG!! Ele abria normalmente em editores, só no visualizador e na Web não, mais estranho era o Safari abrir. Agora está OK! Muito obrigado!